# Change Listbox Order Reflect Changes in XML back end Document

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

Hey guys I am trying to change the order of items inside a listbox C# in a win form and then reflect the changes in the xml document. I am trying to do it with two buttons, Up and Down and it should move the selected list item up or down.  When I try and move up or down I get this exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll.  Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
```

On this line: `lstQuestsSorted.Items.Remove(selected);`

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WinQuestEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private XDocument xDoc;
        private string path;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoadProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "XML| * .xml";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = ofd.FileName;
                xDoc = new XDocument();
                //xDoc.Load(path);
                xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
                var listBoxItems = xDoc.Descendants("EasyQuest").Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value);
                lstQuestBox.DataSource = listBoxItems.ToList();

                var questsSorted = xDoc.Descendants("QuestsSorted").Descendants("QuestsSorted")
                    .Select(x => x.Attribute("Action").Value + " : " + x.Attribute("NameClass").Value);
                lstQuestsSorted.DataSource = questsSorted.ToList();

                var test = "";


            }


        }

        public void MoveUp()
        {
            MoveItem(-1);
        }

        public void MoveDown()
        {
            MoveItem(1);
        }

        public void MoveItem(int direction)
        {
            // Checking selected item
            if (lstQuestsSorted.SelectedItem == null || lstQuestsSorted.SelectedIndex < 0)
                return; // No selected item - nothing to do

            // Calculate new index using move direction
            int newIndex = lstQuestsSorted.SelectedIndex + direction;

            // Checking bounds of the range
            if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= lstQuestsSorted.Items.Count)
                return; // Index out of range - nothing to do

            object selected = lstQuestsSorted.SelectedItem;

            // Removing removable element
            lstQuestsSorted.Items.Remove(selected);
            // Insert it in new position
            lstQuestsSorted.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);
            // Restore selection
            lstQuestsSorted.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
        }

        private void buttonUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MoveItem(-1);
        }

        private void buttonDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MoveItem(1);
        }

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xDoc.Save(path);
            var something = "";
        }

    }
}
```

This is the XML in the background I want to change order with the list.

```
  <QuestsSorted>
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest1" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest2" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest3" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest4" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest5" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest6" />
<QuestsSorted Action="PickUp" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
<QuestsSorted Action="Pulse" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
<QuestsSorted Action="TurnIn" NameClass="ExampleQuest7" />
</QuestsSorted>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obvious, You can not change your listbox order when it is data bound. But you can instead of data bind the list box, add items one by one:

```
 var listBoxItems = xDoc.Descendants("EasyQuest").Select(x=>x.Element("Name").Value).ToList();

 foreach(var item in listBoxItems)
 {
     lstQuestsSorted.Items.add((string)item);
 }
```

Now you can change its order.

To save xml after change order:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XElement QuestsSorted = xDoc.Element("QuestsSorted");
        for (int i = 0; i < lstQuestsSorted.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XElement qt = QuestsSorted.Elements().Skip(i).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
            qt.Attribute("Action").Value = lstQuestsSorted.Items[i].ToString().Split(':')[0];
            qt.Attribute("NameClass").Value = lstQuestsSorted.Items[i].ToString().Split(':')[1];
        }
        xDoc.Save(path);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. So the data is not changing when use xDoc,Save(path). Any more ideas? So I have the document I am trying to change opened in notepad, and I make an edit to the list in the program. Notepad says that this file has been edited do you want to reload, I reload but nothing has changed.

Comment: It is edited and saved but with no changes. It means you did not any change, only save the file.

Comment: Right it just seems to save the same thing as when it first started. So the list box changes, I hit save but the xml in the background isnt changing to reflect the list box changes.

Comment: Why you do not have any save method at the end of MoveItem?

Comment: I have a btn to save the document, ill add it to the code. So I am just doing xDoc,save(path); but nothing gets edited besides the listbox, the xml stays the same.

Comment: xDoc.Save(Path) only? You must affect the xDoc by new changes, then save it.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to figure out now. How to save the changes since the data isnt bound anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134873/discussion-between-farzin-kanzi-and-doobie2012).

Comment: @Doobie2012 I edited my answer and added a method to save QuestsSorted after changes.